# ways to avoid previous reload tornado

Tags: python, angularjs, templates, tornado

I have two forms, when I submit form#1 I get some corresponding file, but when I submit form#2 thenafter, the corresponding file gets shown but form#1 goes empty. So basically I want some thing like a SPA(e.g angular) but I am taking form#1 and form#2 as separate requests routes and each render my index.html every time, so form#2 is wiped off when I submit form#1 and vice-versa.

I dont want a working code but any ideas on how I do that with Tornado (not angular, or say Tornado + Angular ? )

I think one way for example is to handle these requests via a controller and do an AJAX post to corresponding Tornado Handler, which after the file is rendered, displays / serves the very file back again. But this uses AngularJS as a SPA. Any other solution possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Tornado question, as this is simply how Web works.

One possible solution is to have only one form, but display its fields so that they look like two forms; in addition, have two separate submit buttons, each with its own name and value. Now, when you click on either button the whole form will be submitted, but in the handler you can process only the fields associated with the clicked button, while still displaying values in all the fields.

Comment: Oh, ok I see, but I have finally implemented with AngularJS+tornado server a SPA. But even the submit button you spoke of, shall ask a corresponding handler to render a html template which may wipe off the previous filled form.